# How to import an implementation of a trait from another module

Tags: rust, import

I have 3 modules

in lib.rs

Module where I'm trying to import `impl Test for Block` from tra.rs

```
mod tra;
mod stru;

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test() {
        use tra::Test; // This doesn't works

        let b = stru::Block::new(String::from("Text"));

        println!("{}", b.p())
    }
}
```

in stru.rs

Module where struct `Block` is wrote.

```
pub struct Block {
    text: String
}

impl Block {
    pub fn text(&self) -> &String {
        &self.text
    }

    pub fn new(text: String) -> Block {
        Block { text }
    }
}
```

in tra.rs

Module where I'm implementing trait `Test` for `Block`

```
#[path = "stru.rs"]
mod stru;
use stru::Block;


pub trait Test {
    fn p(&self) -> &String;
}

impl Test for Block {
    fn p(&self) -> &String {
        self.text()
    }
}
```

I want to import an implementation from tra.rs into lib.rs. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't import the implementation. You import the trait and that's enough.

Your error is probably because you repeated the `mod stru;` in tra.rs. Don't. Ever. Define modules in lib.rs only (or submodules, but only if they're sub-sub-modules). Instead, just `use` it from the crate root:

```rust
use crate::stru::Block;

pub trait Test {
    fn p(&self) -> &String;
}

impl Test for Block {
    fn p(&self) -> &String {
        self.text()
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! The reason I did that is well.. I'm still don't fully understand how crate system works. I've got this one question.
When do you need to explicitly write `crate`?

Comment: If you want to specify an absolute path, you either need to start with the crate name, or with the keyword `crate` to refer to the current crate. Alternatively, you can use a relative path – `use super::stru::Block` should work here as well. See [the relevant chapter in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html) for further details.

Comment: I have stumbled on another problem... I cannot use modules from lib.rs to main.rs. I'm doing `use crate::boo` in main.rs. I've put every `mod *;` keyword into lib.rs and made them public.

Comment: @Soutgrous When you have both main.rs and lib.rs they're compiled as _separate crates_. Those, you have to use the full crate name. But this is more appropriate for a new SO question.